# How do I send an error to a PassthroughSubject?

Tags: swift, combine

```
let myPassthrough = PassthroughSubject<String, Error>()
```

I know I can send a value to a passthrough subject using `send`:

```
myPassthrough.send("abc")
```

How do I send a failure?

---

I tried:

```
myPassthrough.send(Fail(error: error))
myPassthrough.send(completion: Fail(error: error))
myPassthrough.send(completion: Just(error))
myPassthrough.send(completion: error)
```

None of them compile

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looks like `Subscribers.Completion` is an enum, so this works:

```
myPassthrough.send(completion: .failure(error))
```